# Show excel file in django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

In my django application I am showing the uploaded files like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for i in images %}
    <embed src="{{ i.document.url }}" width="1600"
    height="700"
    type="application/pdf"/>
        <a href="{% url 'employee:delete_product_file' pk=pk %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button" >Delete</a>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
def view_product(request,pk):
    print("function called with pk ",pk)
    images = Uploaded_products.objects.filter(products_connected = pk)
    print("images ",images)
    return render(request, "packsapp/employee/productspdf.html", {'images': images, 'pk': pk})
```

It's working fine when I upload a PDF file but when there is any other format like .docx or any excel file it juts simply downloads the file.

How do I show all the file types in the django template?

I am assuming it has something to do with the `type="application/pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking, but another approach is to publish your files to google drive and then embed them.